# How to set a password for iBall WiFi Router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, password-protection

I use iBall Bation 150m wireless-N ADSL2+Router. Its product code is iB-WRA150N. It enables wired and wireless connections. I want to set a password for wireless, that is for WiFi.

I searched in google but can't find anything useful. How can I set a password ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from this link - 
http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-WiFi-Connection-with-iBall-Baton-150M-Extreme-Wireless-N-Router-on-MTNL-DSL-Modem